# How can I make a 403 error page act like it is the initial page on an htaccess deny?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, ip-address

In my .htaccess file, I am denying a set of IP addresses and allowing all others. I have also set a custom ErrorDocument 403 and pointed it at script.js. I am running script.js through the PHP parser. At the top of the script.js file I set a header of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and `Content-type: application/x-javascript`. If I access the directory I am blocking directly from a blocked IP address I see the javascript code. However, if I do `<script src="http://somedomain.com/check"></script>` the javascript doesn't execute.

What I am going for is, I want the script to only execute from blocked IP addresses. I know I could do this with PHP and have the IP addresses loaded into MySQL however I am blocking A LOT of IPs. I am using CIDR lists from http://www.ipdeny.com/ and I am afraid of the speed problems with doing that.

Any ideas of why it isn't working and how to fix it?

Comment: you probably dont want to know how trivial it is to get around any IP blocking. Most would say so trivial as to make it pointless. even more pointless to do it client side.

Comment: This isn’t for security so yes, it doesn’t matter. It’s to activate a plugin on for people from specific countries. If someone want to get around it, oh well.